# What is font ligature stylistic sets?

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts, ligature, fira-code

I was trying to setup `Fira Code` font on vscode, which supports ligatures.

I came to this [page](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/VS-Code-Instructions), which states,

> Stylistic sets Since version 1.40, you can define stylistic sets in
> settings.json:
>
> "editor.fontLigatures": "'calt', 'ss01', 'ss02', 'ss03', 'ss04',
> 'ss05', 'ss06', 'zero', 'onum'"

I tired `"editor.fontLigatures": true` and ligature works.

*But I wonder now,* ***what difference stylistic sets make?***

Comment: https://www.typography.com/faq/157  -- https://glyphsapp.com/learn/stylistic-sets -- a way to select different glyphs for certain characters across the whole font

Comment: @rioV8 How can I do that in vscode? Does it do it by default? What difference providing these options make while writing code?

Comment: Found some help here -> https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/issues/1203
So those stylistic sets are just different representation of a glyph or a character. 
`Fir Code` offers`zero` without dot inside by default. But if we include `zero` in `fontLigature` zero now becomes dotted, a dot inside zero.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58965575/vscode-update-to-stylistic-sets-using-font-ligatures-with-fira-code and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60924798/cant-get-firacode-to-show-despite-the-font-installed-and-ligatures-activated-in/60958928?r=SearchResults&s=3|47.8236#60958928.