# Font ligatures in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts

Can someone tell me how to obtain this ligatures? It is a specific font or a settings configuration?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i setup font ligatures for Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56209769/how-do-i-setup-font-ligatures-for-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this font named Operator Thin Italic
 it is very expensive like may be 400 USD 
take a look https://www.typography.com/fonts/operator/styles

use Fira Code

Answer (score 2):

Tried running that font from at [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/result) but couldn't find it. Looks like a custom font I guess. A great paid option is Operator Mono which's $200 and a free option is Fira Code.

I suggest you setup FiraCode with ligatures.

**Step #1**: [Install](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/result) Fira Code.

**Step #2**: Set the font in VSCode settings:

```
"editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code, Menlo, Monaco, 'Courier New', monospace",
"editor.fontLigatures": true,
```

**Step #3**: Restart/reload VSCode.

That's about it.