# Not equal symbol instead of exclamation and equal

Tags: visual-studio-code, ligature

I've seen that some people they have Visual Studio Code showing ≠ instead of a classic !=.
Does anyone know how one can enable this option?

I've tried to search for an option to enable this, but I didn't encounter anything in the code editor's settings or the internet.

Comment: I don't know if there's an additional setting you need to enable, but the first thing to do is make sure you're using a font that supports ligatures.

Comment: https://www.itnota.com/enable-font-ligatures-visual-studio-code/ "font ligatures" with a font that supports it, such as "fira code". This Q should probably go to superuser.com, as it is not really about software development.

Answer (score 3):

It's called a [ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligature_(writing)). You need to get a font that supports the specific ligatures that you want to have.

To find out how to set it up for Visual Studio Code, see [How do i setup font ligatures for Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56209769/11107541).

To find such fonts, try googling `programming fonts with ligatures`. I won't list any because Stack Overflow is not for technology recommendations, and I don't want to seed bias or have to maintain a list when new ones become very popular.

Comment: +1 For this! I had Cascadia Code as the selected font in a Git bash shell and couldn't figure out why my git diff results didn't match the source files.